# PHP exec svn export

Tags: php, svn, export, exec

I'm trying to run this exec

```
exec('svn export -r '.$rev2.' '.$repourl.'/'.$dir.$parts[$j].' cache/diff/'.$dir.$parts[$j]);
```

which is equals to:

```
svn export -r 1192 file:///var/svn/Repo/folder/file.xml cache/diff/folder/file.xml
```

when i try the script it simply doesn't export the file (the folde is created with another function, so that one is there.)

but if i try to run the svn export as user www-data (from command line) it works.

so i don't get why it should not work from php.. maybe some configuration?
hope someone can help,
thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Tried also with full path to svn (which svn)
the exec:

```
exec('/usr/bin/svn export -r '.$rev2.' '.$repourl.'/'.$dir.$parts[$j].'
```

the result

```
/usr/bin/svn export -r 1192 file:///var/svn/Repo/folder/file.xml cache/diff/folder/file.xml
```

Still no changes, the file is not exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution,
the problem was related to a global variable not letting the exec run.

Answer (score 0):

It is not configuration. Or rather, not directly. Your PHP instance seems to be set to a user which cannot write to the folder you've specified. Either `chmod` or `chown` it to something that the user which PHP runs as can write to.

Side note: I wrote a SVN lib for laravel. It is, however, standalone. You might want to ease your burden by using it - it itself uses the PECL SVN extension.

Comment: Checed the use (with exec('whoami')) and is **www-data**, the folder is chowned for www-data and has 777 chmod, so i don't think it depends on this (also because executing the command from terminal as www-data works as intended)

Comment: `posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())` will return an assoc array containing all the effective user's info. `name` is what you're after.

Comment: also using the command you suggested return www-data as user, so there should not be any problem

Comment: Other possible causes: are you actually allowed to run `svn`? Instead of exec, run it using passthru and check the output. It might provide helpful clues.